# What programs can i use to connect my android phone to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: android, 20.10

What programs can i use to connect my Android phone to Ubuntu 20.10 that is not KDEConnect or GSConnect. GSConnect and KDEConnect are stupid (in my opinion) and i cannot find any programs for Ubuntu other than the two programs.

(My phone is a Huawei P30 Lite)

Sincerely Mickey

Comment: tell us what desktop enviornment you are using. Desktop enviornments are things like Mate, KDE-Plasma, Gnome, UNity, or a wide array of others exist. Depending on your desktop enviornment, you may use different programs to perform this operation. you probably dont need to install a specific program, the windowing manager probably will handle it. For example, I use ubuntu Mate, I would use caja to open the mount point I would get when attaching the phone to my computer. I I were using a desktop enviorment other than Mate, I wouldnt use caja, I would use the system default.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you want to achieve through connecting the Android and Ubuntu devices and also without knowing why you think KDEConnect-based solutions are "stupid", I'll present the following two file sharing options.

1. https://snapdrop.net/ can share files between devices and you don't even need to install anything.
2. https://trebleshot.monora.org/ can share files between Android and Linux

Source: https://linuxhint.com/wireless_file_sharing_apps_linux_android/

Hope this helps.

---

Update (Jan 07 2021):

I've also discovered scrcpy

3. https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

which lets you display your phone's screen and control your device.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Thanks for the answer